# creating a table with two foreign keys in consideration

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE TABLE youth(
  yh_id int NOT NULL,
  surname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  post VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (yh_id), REFERENCES members (mbrs_id) FOREIGN KEY (mbrs_id);
```

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "REFERENCES"
> LINE 5:   PRIMARY KEY (yh_id), REFERENCES members (mbrs_id) FOREIGN ...
> ^
> SQL state: 42601
> Character: 128

Comment: You have `references` and `foreign key` in the wrong order: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html

Comment: Also `FOREIGN KEY (mbrs_id)` needs to point to a column in the referencing(child) table in this case `youth` and I don't see `mbrs_id` in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with the correct syntax.

> ```
> create table members (
> mbrs_id int primary key);
> CREATE TABLE youth(
>   yh_id int NOT NULL,
>   surname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
>   post VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
>  CONSTRAINT pk_youth_yh_id PRIMARY KEY (yh_id), 
>  CONSTRAINT fk_youth_members_mbrs_id FOREIGN KEY (yh_id) REFERENCES members (mbrs_id) );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into members values(1);
> insert into youth values
> (1,'Jones','manager');
> ```

1 rows affected

> 

1 rows affected

> 

> ```
> insert into youth values
> (2,'Smith','chairman');
> ```
>
> ```
> ERROR:  insert or update on table "youth" violates foreign key constraint "fk_youth_members_mbrs_id"
> ```

DETAIL:  Key (yh_id)=(2) is not present in table "members".

> 

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=8240826d1433f7f6b94ce10d88192366)*